# In R: remove with multiple conditions across variables

Tags: r

I would like to remove those observations (by companyID) where group is 1, and there are two observations for a year (where one observation concerns type B and the other type K). It is probably simpler to understand by my example below.

Here is a sample of the dataset I have:

```
companyID  type  group  year
    1       B      1    2006
    1       K      1    2006
    1       B      1    2007
    2       B      1    2001
    2       B      1    2002
    2       K      1    2002
    2       K      2    2003
    3       B      1    2010
    3       K      1    2010
    3       K      2    2011
```

and this my preferred outcome:

```
companyID  type  group  year
    1       B      1    2007
    2       B      1    2001
    2       K      2    2003
    3       K      2    2011
```

thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

use this code/syntax for `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(companyID, year) %>%
  filter(n() == 1 , n_distinct(type) == 1)

# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   companyID, year [4]
  companyID type  group  year
      <int> <chr> <int> <int>
1         1 B         1  2007
2         2 B         1  2001
3         2 K         2  2003
4         3 K         2  2011
```

the second condition doesn't work and is thus redundant in your given sample.  However, as you have specified, I have included that as condition.  The following will also work

```
df %>% group_by(companyID, year) %>%
  filter(!n() > 1 , !n_distinct(type) > 1)
```

baseR way

```
subset(df, as.numeric(ave(df$type, paste(df$companyID, df$year),  FUN = length)) == 1)

   companyID type group year
3          1    B     1 2007
4          2    B     1 2001
7          2    K     2 2003
10         3    K     2 2011
```

OR

```
subset(df, as.numeric(ave(df$companyID, paste(df$companyID, df$year),  FUN = length)) == 1 & 
         as.numeric(ave(df$type, paste(df$companyID, df$year),  FUN = function(x) length(unique(x)))) == 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Base solution

```
do.call(
  rbind,
  by(df,list(df$companyID,df$group,df$year),function(x){
    if ((nrow(x)!=2 & x$group[1]==1) | x$group[1]!=1) {
      x
    }
  })
)

   companyID type group year
4          2    B     1 2001
7          2    K     2 2003
3          1    B     1 2007
10         3    K     2 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data.table` solution:

```
library(data.table)

dat = fread('companyID  type  group  year
    1       B      1    2006
    1       K      1    2006
    1       B      1    2007
    2       B      1    2001
    2       B      1    2002
    2       K      1    2002
    2       K      2    2003
    3       B      1    2010
    3       K      1    2010
    3       K      2    2011')

result = dat[, types:= uniqueN(type), by = .(companyID, group, year)][group != 1 | types == 1][, types:= NULL]

> result
   companyID type group year
1:         1    B     1 2007
2:         2    B     1 2001
3:         2    K     2 2003
4:         3    K     2 2011
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you just need to group by `group` and `year`.

```
df %>% group_by(group, year) %>% filter(n() < 2)
```

Output:

```
#   companyID type  group  year
#       <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1         1 B         1  2007
# 2         2 B         1  2001
# 3         2 K         2  2003
# 4         3 K         2  2011
```